# How to concatenate string message with column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add custom message for my sql query result but can't find exactly how can I achieve that. below is what I tried with my sql query.

```
Select 
    'The Maximum Rating of the city'  " + city + "  'is=' " + MAX(rating) + "
From 
    CUSTOMER 
Where 
    CITY is not null 
Group by 
    CITY;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the *Double quotes* and last `+` operator

```
Select 'The Maximum Rating of the city '+city+' is = '+ cast(MAX(rating) as varchar(50))
from CUSTOMER 
where CITY is not null 
group by CITY;
```

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then you can use [*`Concat`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh231515.aspx) function which does not require explicit conversion

```
Select Concat('The Maximum Rating of the city ',city,' is = ', MAX(rating))
from CUSTOMER 
where CITY is not null 
group by CITY;
```

Comment: Also tried that, getting error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @zee - Updated check now. Since `rating` is of `Numeric` type we need to explicitly convert it to `varchar`